# Is there a difference between using "!== null" and simply not having it at all?

Tags: javascript, null

If you are trying to determine if a variable is not null, you could write

```
if (a !== null)
```

but I was wondering is this the same thing as writing

```
if (a)
```

?

Comment: Mostly, but what if `a` is `0`, `'0'` or `false`?

Comment: No, because truthiness and an explicit inequality check are distinctly different things. This is covered in many JS language guides and tutorials. "Strictly not null" is not the same as truthy.

Comment: (Noting that the `'0'` in the first comment behaves differently than `0` and `false`.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Oh yeah? That's interesting. What kind of differences are there? At a glance with some basic `'0' == true/false` vs `0 == true/false` vs `false == true/false` tests, it seems to behave the same...

Comment: @TimLewis Those are different comparisons because coercion is taking place. Try an equivalent expression, e.g., `if ('0') console.log('ohai')`

Comment: @DaveNewton Yup, just got to that one, you're totally right.

Comment: @TimLewis It happens on rare occasions ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm a PHP dev primarily, and seeing that behaviour in JS is odd... `if('0') { echo 'Oh hai'; } else { echo 'Weird'; }` returns `'weird'` :)

Comment: @TimLewis https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Answer (score 1):

Null is one of the primitive values in javascript. 'null' and 'undefined' both denotes no value for a particular variable.

Difference between the two is:

'null': Variable has been declared but not yet assigned any value (Intentional absence of value)
'undefined': Variable that has been declared but not assigned any value is undefined, not null.

For example:

```
var a= null; // it has no value and user defined false value as null
var b; // b also has no value which is undefined assigned by js compiler
```

In order to check if a value is null or not you can use either one of the following:

```
var a = null;
if(a) {console.log("Not null");} else {console.log("Value is null");} // Value is null

a==null //true
a== undefined // true (This can be used in sitaution where you need no worry about null or undefined and are just concerned with no values)
a=== null //true

//Lastly you can also use ES6 inbuilt function to check for null values
//as type of null is object you can use the following approach

Object.is(maybeNull,null) //true
```

Coming to your question, yes both the conditions you mentioned will work fine to check for null values.